# Save new clicked value "type" to jsonObject file?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to be able to save my new clicked value(type) to my jsonObject file.
In a menu I can choose type values `c`, `r` and `e`, and when choosing, for example, `c`, I want to save that value(type) to my `jsonObject` file.

```
function populateTypes() {
    for (var k in jsonObjects) {
        var type = jsonObjects[k].type;
        if (availableTypes.indexOf(type) < 0) {
            availableTypes.push(type);
            $('#changetotypes').append('<li><a class="typechange" href="#" data-type="' + type + '">' + type + '</a></li>');
       }
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '.typechange', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $('#currenttype').html('Aktuell Typ: ' + type);
});
```

This my jsonObject file:

```
"c3000": {"x": 675, "y": 269, "plan":1, "name":"c3000", "img":"sensor3.png", "added":"datetime", "type":"c", "interval":"0", "comment":"enmassatext", "active":true, "value":"4c", "radie":false, "alarm":false},
"r3002": {"x": 223, "y": 355, "plan":1, "name":"r3002", "img":"sensor2.png", "added":"datetime", "type":"r", "interval":"6", "comment":"enmassatext", "active":true, "value":"-4c", "radie":false, "alarm":true},
"r3003": {"x": 300, "y": 100, "plan":1, "name":"r3003", "img":"sensor1.png", "added":"datetime", "type":"e", "interval":"3", "comment":"enmassatext", "active":false, "value":"15c", "radie":false, "alarm":false},
```

Comment: So what would you JSON look like after you've made your save?  And if you click a different link later do you have to update the data you've saved to your JSON store or simply append to it?

Comment: @Scott Sauyet When I refresh the page the value(type), Its changing back to the default value(type). Its not saving the new value(types).

Comment: Saving your information back to a server is a very different job than updating a Javascript object in memory.  You don't keep a client-side reference to a server-side file.  Saving this will take a separate mechanism, probably involving AJAX calls.

Comment: @Scott Sauyet Ok, I understand, but can you give me a hint on how to use AJAX calls?

Comment: You're going to have to do a little research.  AJAX is not hard, but StackOverflow comments are not the right venue for a tutorial.  Nor will AJAX alone solve your issue, as you will still need a server-side to save your data; and in the end, it's unlikely that you'll want to store it in a static file you serve up with your page.  You have some research to do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every element on your page has an `id`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.typechange', function (e) {
    var el = $(this);

    jsonObjects[el.attr("id")] = {
      // populate your object here
      "data": el.data('type');
    };

    e.preventDefault();    
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    $('#currenttype').html('Aktuell Typ: ' + type);
});
```

This will update your JSON object, now how you have to figure out how to write this back to your original JSON file.

Comment: Every elements dont have an ID, and your code is not working, Its missing a }.

Comment: And you are probably clever enough to fix this yourself on your code :)

Comment: Ok, Im gonna try to fix my code. Its not working if you put "data": el.data('type');, delete ; at the end...